# How to enable VA-API in VLC in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, vlc, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I can't enable VA-API in VLC (the VA-API output is not present among the one I can choose, only VDPAU, OpenGL GLX, X11, XCB, framebuffer, etc.).

I have an Intel i5-4200M CPU, using the integrated GPU.

On the same hardware all was working fine with Ubuntu 14.04, using either packages from the official repos or from ppa https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests

I searched a lot but couldn't find what is wrong.

The following packages are installed:

```
vlc 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4
libva1 1.8.1-1~xenial
libva-x11-1 1.8.1-1~xenial
libva-wayland1 1.8.1-1~xenial (although I don't use Wayland)
libva-drm1 1.8.1-1~xenial
i965-va-driver 1.8.1-1~xenial
```

vainfo reports:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.40.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_40
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.40 (libva )
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Haswell Mobile - 1.8.1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
```

On other pages I read `libva-intel-vaapi-driver` should be installed, but no candidate exists: I also read it's just a source package upon which `i965-va-driver` is built, so I should be fine with it.

vainfo output seems to suggest all is fine, in fact with this configuration, as I already said, I could choose VA-API in VLC output preferences with Ubuntu 14.04, but I can't with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Maybe try install the snap version of VLC and try whether VA-API works with it. (Execute "snap run vlc" to make sure you're not getting the DEB version.) 
Another thing you can try is to use mpv. Running mpv from the terminal prints really helpful debug messages, I have found.

Comment: VLC from snap brings VLC 3.0.10 and I do have VA-API and VA-API via DRM (what is better?). Shell output reveals it's working. Probably because it uses a whole different stack? Leaving "auto" makes VLC try to use VDPAU and fails (`Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`). mpv is another mystery: it used to work (I'm 100% sure) but right now it doesn't use VA-API either: no useful log, just a laconic `Looking at hwdec h264-vaapi...` followed by attempts to load other hwdec drivers and then a final `Using software decoding`...